# Extract Unique IP sources from pcap file

Tags: wireshark

My approach is to:

1 - Use tshark and export the list in a txt file.

```
tshark -r file.cap -T fields -e ip.src > output.txt
```

2 - Use sort to delete the double ips

```
sort output.txt | uniq > uniqueip.txt
```

3 - use uniqueip.txt to count the lines with

```
wc -l output.txt
```

I noticed right after i get the output.txt has some strange formatting where some ips are in line? why are they not in a new line?

This it the output.txt

```
"58.176.204.64"
"180.168.211.204"
"103.248.63.253"
"216.245.214.196,146.231.254.240"
"112.104.105.79"
"216.245.214.196,146.231.254.131"
"112.104.105.79"
"10.0.61.65,146.231.254.12"
```

Comment: Could you temporarily provide a sample `file.cap`? It's hard to help you without knowing what your input looks like. The commands look OK, except the last one. You probably meant to write: `wc -l uniqueip.txt`. But that doesn't really solve your problems. We need your input file.

Comment: Also, take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did some correction in the post, I had 200mb, I split it in 10mb, test it again but the problem remains. but i am not sure how to upload a pcap file here in stackoverflow.

Comment: @bostongeorge Try any of the free file hosting providers: MEGA, Dropbox, Google Drive, ....

Comment: file link here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fb4c5f8dea963526d67ca353f511461020221016185525/e9ae650af6a880921898388da00842a820221016185538/b41c26

Answer (score 1):

The reason why some lines contain more than 1 IP address separated by a comma is because the packet itself contains more than 1 IP header.  Such is the case for tunneling protocols or for ICMP error packets whose payload contains the original IP header that caused the ICMP error packet to be sent in the first place, or for other types of packets as well.

Comment: The OPs `.cap` file confirms this answer. +1

Comment: I read now that is because of the ICMP type 3. But this problem is not there if you use tcpdump instead of tshark apparently.

Comment: FYI: I opened a `tshark` enhancement bug request that, if  implemented, would allow you to specify `-e ip.src#1` so that only the outer IP source address field would be displayed and not the inner IP source address.  Ref: https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues/18499